# How do I wrap each iteration of a loop in separate div containers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of objects that are nested inside an array. I was able to append each object's property to a specific element (i.e. the "title" property is placed in a H1 element, etc.); however, I would like each object and all of it's properties to be wrapped within a separate DIV element per object.  As of now, all of the objects are in one div. I was thinking maybe a forEach loop might be necessary.  I've tried messing around with it and can't seem to figure this out although it seems like it should be fairly simple.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  margin:50px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

And the Script:

```
var ads = [
    {
        title: "Title 1",
        description: "Lorum ipsum dolor",
        start_date: "2018-09-01",
        end_date: "2018-12-30",
        offer: "50% Off",
        num_of_products: 7
    },
    {
        title: "Title 2",
        description: "Lorum ipsom",
        start_date: "2018-08-01",
        end_date: "2018-11-30",
        offer: "Save $25",
        num_of_products: 10
    },
    {
        title: "Title 3",
        description: "Lorum ipsum dolor etc",
        start_date: "2018-09-01",
        end_date: "2018-10-30",
        offer: "35% Off",
        num_of_products: 8
    },

];


    const parent = document.getElementById("container");

  for( { title, description, start_date, end_date, offer, num_of_products } of ads) {

    const headline = document.createElement("h1");
    headline.textContent = title;
    const descrip = document.createElement("p");
    descrip.textContent = description;    
    const dates = document.createElement("sub");
    dates.textContent = "Offer valid " + start_date + " through " + end_date;    
    const discount = document.createElement("h2");
    discount.textContent = offer;    
    const products = document.createElement("h4");
    products.textContent = num_of_products + " items still available! " ;

   // append 
    parent.appendChild(headline);
    parent.appendChild(discount);
    parent.appendChild(descrip);
    parent.appendChild(products);
    parent.appendChild(dates);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create wrapper div for each iteration as following and apply your custom class for it then add all element into this div then add the div to main container

```
const parent = document.getElementById("container");

  for( { title, description, start_date, end_date, offer, num_of_products } of ads) {

    const wrapper =  document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.className = "container"; // you can add your class for it
    const headline = document.createElement("h1");
    headline.textContent = title;
    const descrip = document.createElement("p");
    descrip.textContent = description;    
    const dates = document.createElement("sub");
    dates.textContent = "Offer valid " + start_date + " through " + end_date;    
    const discount = document.createElement("h2");
    discount.textContent = offer;    
    const products = document.createElement("h4");
    products.textContent = num_of_products + " items still available! " ;

   // append 
    wrapper.appendChild(headline);
    wrapper.appendChild(discount);
    wrapper.appendChild(descrip);
    wrapper.appendChild(products);
    wrapper.appendChild(dates);
    parent.appendChild(wrapper);
 }
```

Comment: Ah!  Okay thank you!  I had tried this, but I forgot to append the wrapper to the parent.  That was actually very simple haha

Comment: I actually had to place this const parent = document.getElementById("container");   inside the for loop.  but other than that it worked fine.

Comment: no need to add it inside the for loop because you need to get it only one time then append to it inside the loop

Comment: Ah, ok I fixed that.  It was working fine in codepen but in my browser console I'm getting an error that says there is an uncaught typeError: cannot read property "appendChild" of null for the last line where I'm appending the wrapper to the parent... so I'm not sure why that is.  Also in the browser the js doesn't seem to be showing up at all for me but I have it linked to the html page.  Any ideas?

Comment: this error means that you don't have <div id='container'></div> element in you you document so document.getElementById("container") reruns null

Comment: I figured out the issue!  I had my external js file linked in the <head> tag so it was loading before my html.  I moved it to the bottom of the body section and it's working fine now. :)  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 6):

For this, I would use a lightweight library called lit-html, which is perfectly suited for these kinds of jobs:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="module">
  import { html, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html/lit-html.js?module'
  import { repeat } from 'https://unpkg.com/lit-html/directives/repeat.js?module'

  const offerTemplate = ({title, description, start_date, end_date, offer, num_of_products}) => html`
    <article>
      <h1>${title}</h1>
      <p>${description}</p>
      <sub>Offer valid ${start_date} through ${end_date}</sub>
      <h2>${offer}</h2>
      <h4>${num_of_products} items still available!</h4>
    </article>`

  const offersTemplate = offers => html`${repeat(offers, offerTemplate)}`

  render(offersTemplate(ads), document.getElementById('container'))
</script>
```

A popular pattern is to define the leaf of the iteration as its own custom element:

```
const offerTemplate = ad => html`
  <ads-offer
      title="${ad.title}"
      description="${ad.description}"
      start-date="${ad.start_date}"
      end-date="${ad.end_date}
      offer="${ad.offer}"
      num-products="${ad.num_of_products}"
  ></ads-offer>`
```

In which you could define the DOM for `<ads-offer>` separately and independently from the collection.

Comment: I think this deserves more likes for such answer.